# JavaScript fetch get headers

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I get the response I am looking for using postman if I use this URL:

```
https://od-api.oxforddictionaries.com:443/api/v1/entries/en/word
```

and these headers:

```
Accept:application/json
app_id:vb805en4
app_key:bmd3a11b2951277c3a04ddbbnaec0216
```

but my JavaScript fetch is not working

```
const url = 'https://api.oxforddictionaries.com:443/api/v1/entries/en/'
let searchString = 'word'

fetch(url + searchString, {
  method: 'get',
  headers: {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "app_id": "vb805en4",
    "app_key": "bmd3a11b2951277c3a04ddbbnaec0216"
  }
})  
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(myJson) {
    console.log(myJson);
  });
```

here is the non working replit
https://repl.it/@jasenmichael/oxford-fetch

Comment: it is a CORS issue, I guess

Comment: so yes it is a cors error, chome dev tools gives me this...

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://api.oxforddictionaries.com:443/api/v1/entries/en/word. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

since I do not have access to the server, and it works for me locally using postman.. what headers do I need in my fetch to make this work? any help appreciated.. cheers

Comment: https://forum.oxforddictionaries.com/api/discussion/18/error-message-no-access-control-allow-origin-or-i-can-t-get-my-client-side-request-to-work#latest This API doesn't allow it, you would need to use a server as a proxy. By the way, are you sure you want to keep these credentials widely visible to anyone?

Comment: I did end up just building an express(with cors) proxy server, but I am curious why I can make the get request via postman, but not via the client directly? 

Yes I know the risk of sharing keys, this is a free account with no ability to post data, plus I have already changed the keys.

Comment: Because postman is an extension and hence has access to priviledges web APIs don't, such as overcoming cross-origin restrictions.